# dell desktop going into sleep mode when I start it and not waking up

Tags: windows-7, bsod, virus

OS - Windows 7 Home

I updated some virtualbox machine stuff (like upgrading the software and deleting some virtual machines and creating some new ones) and then updated some divx (that also installed some web-player, codec etc).

I was asked to reboot the computer after divx installation, so I did. After having BSOD a couple of times, the computer is now going to sleep after 2 minutes or so after I start it no matter what I do - bios, safe mode, normal, recovery disk, **which also means I haven't able to log-into my computer ever since I installed/changed all this stuff but I did get as far as seeing windows logo.**

So I don't know whether virtualbox did it or divx did it, but I am leaning towards divx.  The update caused some motherboard-level virus-infection or maybe video card failed co-incidentally at the same time I updated Divx etc?!

How could I possibly fix it?

1)Tried different monitor
2)Tried resetting bios to default

I'm all willing to format my computer and such, except the computer will just go to sleep and I can't see anything! **(By sleep, I mean it's still running and everything - I can tell by the loud fans at least. The monitor says - "entering power save" and then there is orange light instead of green on monitor's power button)**

Comment: Does it happen also when booting from the installation/recovery CD?
If it does, do you have enough time to see the installation menu?

Comment: @OfirLuzon Yes, it also happens when booting from installation/recovery cd. I do have enough time to see menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problem, I had about 5 minutes until the monitor went into sleep mode (I also tried different monitors).
I took a chance and reinstalled windows from the installation CD, the screen turned in the process.

I actually repeated it 3 times:

1. I formated and set the pertitions I wanted. (screen went off, hard reboot after some quiet time)
2. I initiated the installer, and randomly pressed `Enter` whenever the PC (fan) was quiet. (hard reboot after pressing `Enter` does not do anything (fan noise)
3. Installed again, this time actually seeing the option I choose.

Keep in mind this is a long shot, and I did format my PC in the dark. I guess it could also go bad.

Good luck